# Express $x_1$ from the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could you kindly help me express $x_1$ from the equation below?

$$y = \frac{ x_1^3 - x_2^3 }{ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + 1}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Is this $$y=\frac{x_1^3-x_2^3}{x_1^2+x_2^2+1}$$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I can multiply y with the denominator and then express x1^2 but still get a 3rd degree of polynomial equation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have to solve the equation $$0=x_1^3-x_1^2y-x_2^2y-y-x_2^3$$ this is a polynomial of degree three. Look for the Cardano formulas.

Comment: I'll look it up and reply back, thanks.

Comment: I've investigated the theorem and other cubic equation solving methods, but they are for solving the equation if I have constants and coefficients in it. However currently I have variables and I'd like to express one of them. Any more ideas that could take me closer to solving my initial requirement? Thanks.

Comment: You just treat $y$ and $x_2$ as if they were constants, and use Cardano.

Comment: Think about the quadratic formula. It solves $ax^2+bx+c=0$. What are $a,b,c$? You can call them constants, but you can also call them variables. Variables are just placeholders for constants, you can treat them and manipulate them the same way you do with constants.

Comment: So, horv, where are we now on this matter?